# Overflowing :: Using flexbox

Tags: html, css, web

I know there has been a lot of questions and answers about how to control the overflow of a parent container using `flexbox`. I couldn't find a solution to this problem so here is another question about it.

**What I want**
The part where the problem is, is commented in the `HTML`. 
[image]

**What I get**

[image]

Here is the code. You might have to copy and paste the code in...:(

```css
html {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#voolvern_main .voolvern_grid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.voolvern_gflex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  height: -webkit-fit-content;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
}

.voolvern_grid .voolvern_gridflex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

#voolvern_main {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  #voolvern_pcard_section.voolvern_stack_two .voolvern_item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 56rem) {
  #voolvern_pcard_section.voolvern_stack_two .voolvern_item {
    width: 32.99999%;
  }
}

#voolvern_main>#voolvern_mainaside.voolvern_aside {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 1rem;
  flex: 1 1 1rem;
}

#voolvern_main>#voolvern_rightaside.voolvern_aside {
  width: 32%;
}

#voolvern_main>.voolvern_aside>.voolvern_uid {
  width: 100%;
}

.voolvern_stackhandler>.voolvern_stackpad {
  padding-right: 1.2rem;
  padding-left: 1.2rem;
}

.voolvern_group.voolvern_nuid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#voolvern_toolbar>.voolvern_group {
  padding-top: 1.7rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.7rem;
}

#voolvern_toolbar>.voolvern_group.voolvern_nuid>.voolvern_nitem .voolvern_span {
  padding-top: .8rem;
  padding-bottom: .8rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

#voolvern_toolbar>.voolvern_group.voolvern_nuid>.voolvern_nitem .voolvern_span:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}

.voolvern_stackpad>.voolvern_header>.voolvern_group {
  height: 3.5rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/db35900820.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free-v4-font-face.min.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free-v4-shims.min.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css" media="all">
  <title>vvnfinal</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1097/screenshots/168079/newv2.png">
</head>

<body class="voolvern_grid">
  <main id="voolvern_main" class="voolvern_gridflex" style="flex: 1rem">
    <aside id="voolvern_mainaside" class="voolvern_aside voolvern_gridflex">
      <section class="voolvern_uid voolvern_stackhandler" style=" flex-direction: column; display: flex">
        <!-- begin:: header -->
        <div class="voolvern_stackpad">
          <section id="voolvern_mainasideheader" class="voolvern_header">
            <div class="voolvern_group voolvern_nuid">
              <span>left</span>
              <span>left</span>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <!-- end:: header -->
        <div style="flex: 1; border-bottom: .01rem solid lightgray">
          <section style="overflow-y: scroll;">
            <!-- here is the div that when givin a height of 40rem+ it cuzes the <section> to push down all the contents after it,
I want the <section> to stay put and is scrollable when that happens but I can't seem to figure that out. 

 -->
            <div style="height: 40rem">content</div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <!-- begin:: toolbar -->
        <div class="voolvern_stackpad">
          <section id="voolvern_toolbar">
            <span class="voolvern_group voolvern_nuid">
              <!-- begin:: toolbar items -->
              <div class="voolvern_nitem">
                <a href="/Projects">
                  <span class="voolvern_span">
                    <i class="far fa-lightbulb" aria-hidden="true">
                    </i>
                  </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="voolvern_nitem">
          <a href="/Subsidiaries" class="">
            <span class="voolvern_span">
                    <i class="fab fa-hubspot" aria-hidden="true">
                    </i>
                  </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="voolvern_nitem">
          <a href="/Discover" class="">
            <span class="voolvern_span">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true">
                    </i>
                  </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="voolvern_nitem">
          <a href="/Discover" class="">
            <span class="voolvern_span">
                    <i class="fas fa-globe-americas" aria-hidden="true">
                    </i>
                  </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="voolvern_nitem">
          <a href="/Support" class="">
            <span class="voolvern_span">
                    <i class="fas fa-hands-helping" aria-hidden="true">
                    </i>
                  </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="voolvern_nitem">
          <a href="/Support" class="">
            <span class="voolvern_span">
                    <i class="fab fa-ioxhost" aria-hidden="true">
                    </i>
                  </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- end:: toolbar itemns-->
        </span>
        </section>
        </div>
        <!-- end:: toolbar -->
      </section>
    </aside>
    <aside id="voolvern_rightaside" class="voolvern_aside voolvern_nuid">
      <section class="voolvern_uid voolvern_stackhandler" style="overflow-y: scroll">
        <!-- begin:: header -->
        <div class="voolvern_stackpad">
          <section id="voolvern_rightasideheader" class="voolvern_header">
            <div class="voolvern_group"> content header </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <!-- end:: header -->
      </section>
    </aside>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

This whole site will be built using `flexbox`
Meaning I use:

```
display: flex
flex: 1 
flex-direction: column
```

To get the full height from elements.

I have spent 2 months trying to figure this problem out. 
I would greatly appreciate it if we can solve this problem swiftly. 
Thank you!

Comment: I'm in a rush if this question seems too broad let me know!

Comment: So... you want a toolbar fixed at the bottom?

Comment: @isacvale the toolbar is already pushed to the bottom by giving the element before it a flex: 1. But when that element gets any content that is longer than itself it pushes the toolbar down even more past view. I'm trying to get that element use the overflow-y: scroll; so that it does not push the toolbar down..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the overflow work correctly you need to position the element you want to do the overflow absolutely. I had the same issue and searched a long time to find this solution. Looks like this is a common behavior when using flex layout.

Here is the relevant change:

```
<div style="flex: 1; border-bottom: .01rem solid lightgray; position: relative;">
    <section style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll;">
       <div style="height: 40rem">content</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

And the changes=d snippet where you can see it work.

```css
html {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#voolvern_main .voolvern_grid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.voolvern_gflex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  height: -webkit-fit-content;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
}

.voolvern_grid .voolvern_gridflex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

#voolvern_main {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  #voolvern_pcard_section.voolvern_stack_two .voolvern_item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 56rem) {
  #voolvern_pcard_section.voolvern_stack_two .voolvern_item {
    width: 32.99999%;
  }
}

#voolvern_main>#voolvern_mainaside.voolvern_aside {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 1rem;
  flex: 1 1 1rem;
}

#voolvern_main>#voolvern_rightaside.voolvern_aside {
  width: 32%;
}

#voolvern_main>.voolvern_aside>.voolvern_uid {
  width: 100%;
}

.voolvern_stackhandler>.voolvern_stackpad {
  padding-right: 1.2rem;
  padding-left: 1.2rem;
}

.voolvern_group.voolvern_nuid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#voolvern_toolbar>.voolvern_group {
  padding-top: 1.7rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.7rem;
}

#voolvern_toolbar>.voolvern_group.voolvern_nuid>.voolvern_nitem .voolvern_span {
  padding-top: .8rem;
  padding-bottom: .8rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

#voolvern_toolbar>.voolvern_group.voolvern_nuid>.voolvern_nitem .voolvern_span:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}

.voolvern_stackpad>.voolvern_header>.voolvern_group {
  height: 3.5rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/db35900820.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free-v4-font-face.min.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free-v4-shims.min.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css" media="all">
  <title>vvnfinal</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1097/screenshots/168079/newv2.png">
</head>

<body class="voolvern_grid">
  <main id="voolvern_main" class="voolvern_gridflex" style="flex: 1rem">
    <aside id="voolvern_mainaside" class="voolvern_aside voolvern_gridflex">
      <section class="voolvern_uid voolvern_stackhandler" style=" flex-direction: column; display: flex">
        <!-- begin:: header -->
        <div class="voolvern_stackpad">
          <section id="voolvern_mainasideheader" class="voolvern_header">
            <div class="voolvern_group voolvern_nuid">
              <span>left</span>
              <span>left</span>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <!-- end:: header -->
        <div style="flex: 1; border-bottom: .01rem solid lightgray; position: relative;">
          <section style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll;">
            <!-- here is the div that when givin a height of 40rem+ it cuzes the <section> to push down all the contents after it,
I want the <section> to stay put and is scrollable when that happens but I can't seem to figure that out. 

 -->
            <div style="height: 40rem">content</div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <!-- begin:: toolbar -->
        <div class="voolvern_stackpad">
          <section id="voolvern_toolbar">
            <span class="voolvern_group voolvern_nuid">
              <!-- begin:: toolbar items -->
              <div class="voolvern_nitem">
                <a href="/Projects">
                  <span class="voolvern_span">
                    <i class="far fa-lightbulb" aria-hidden="true">
                    </i>
                  </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="voolvern_nitem">
          <a href="/Subsidiaries" class="">
            <span class="voolvern_span">
                    <i class="fab fa-hubspot" aria-hidden="true">
                    </i>
                  </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="voolvern_nitem">
          <a href="/Discover" class="">
            <span class="voolvern_span">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true">
                    </i>
                  </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="voolvern_nitem">
          <a href="/Discover" class="">
            <span class="voolvern_span">
                    <i class="fas fa-globe-americas" aria-hidden="true">
                    </i>
                  </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="voolvern_nitem">
          <a href="/Support" class="">
            <span class="voolvern_span">
                    <i class="fas fa-hands-helping" aria-hidden="true">
                    </i>
                  </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="voolvern_nitem">
          <a href="/Support" class="">
            <span class="voolvern_span">
                    <i class="fab fa-ioxhost" aria-hidden="true">
                    </i>
                  </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- end:: toolbar itemns-->
        </span>
        </section>
        </div>
        <!-- end:: toolbar -->
      </section>
    </aside>
    <aside id="voolvern_rightaside" class="voolvern_aside voolvern_nuid">
      <section class="voolvern_uid voolvern_stackhandler" style="overflow-y: scroll">
        <!-- begin:: header -->
        <div class="voolvern_stackpad">
          <section id="voolvern_rightasideheader" class="voolvern_header">
            <div class="voolvern_group"> content header </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <!-- end:: header -->
      </section>
    </aside>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yess! Perfect. Thank you! I did think there was another way of fixing this problem using flexbox, but this solution works perfectly; Thanks @AlesD